# ¿Cómo configurar correctamente el fichero .pom de maven - java?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Jamás he usado Maven, apenas sé de que se trata.

Tengo una aplicación java que usa Maven y estoy usando el IDE Eclipse. El problema que se me presenta es que, al ejecutar la aplicación desde Eclipse funciona perfectamente pero si ejecuto el .jar no hace nada.

Para intentar ver qué sucedería, ejecuté el fichero .jar desde el CMD con el siguiente comando:

```
java -jar "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Codigo Java Eclipse 4.15\myapp\target\file.jar"
```

El resultado:

**no hay ningún atributo de manifiesto principal en C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Codigo Java Eclipse 4.15\myapp\target\file.jar**

Investigando un poco, he visto que existen dos opciones de solucionarlo:

**Opción 1.** Indicar la clase main desde consola con el siguiente comando:

```
java -cp "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Codigo Java Eclipse 4.15\myapp\target\file.jar" com.loquesea.MyMain
```

Resultado: **Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/loquesea/loquesea2/meta/exceptions/LoQueSeaApiException**

**Opción 2.** Configurar el fichero .pom añadiendo:

```
  <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <!-- <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> -->
                        <mainClass>com.loquesea.MyMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

El problema es que todos los ejemplos que vi van encerrados en `<build></build>` y mi .pom tiene `<project></project>`

Intenté hacerlo de esta forma pero está mal formado:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <groupId>Loquesea</groupId>
            <artifactId>loquesea</artifactId>
            <version>20.04.14</version>
            <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.loquesea</groupId>
                    <artifactId>loquesea2</artifactId>
                    <version>4.7</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <!-- <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> -->
                        <mainClass>com.loquesea.MyMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
</build>
```

El original del proyecto es este:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Loquesea</groupId>
    <artifactId>Loquesea</artifactId>
    <version>20.04.14</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.loquesea</groupId>
            <artifactId>loquesea2</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema creo que son las dependencias:

Cuando usas Maven para crear una aplicación de cualquier tipo, dejas que Maven gestione las dependencias. En tu caso tienes un proyecto que se identifica con

```
<groupId>Loquesea</groupId>
<artifactId>Loquesea</artifactId>
<version>20.04.14</version>
```

Y que tiene como dependencia otro proyecto que se identifica con

```
<groupId>org.loquesea</groupId>
<artifactId>loquesea2</artifactId>
<version>4.7</version>
```

Cuando ejecutas el proyecto desde Eclipse, el IDE sabe que es un proyecto Maven y añade todas las dependencias de tu jar al classpath en la línea de comandos, algo como:

```
java -cp "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Codigo Java Eclipse 4.15\myapp\target\file.jar;C:\Users\myuser\.m2\repository\org\loquesea\loquesea2\4.7\loquesea2.jar" com.loquesea.MyMain
```

Por dejarlo claro: `-cp` significa *classpath*, y aquí se definen todos los archivos que deben tenerse en cuenta a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación. Tanto en Windows como en Linux/Mac se usa la misma sintaxis que al definir la variable de entorno del sistema `PATH` (esto significa usar `;` para separar distintas rutas en Windows y usar `:` en el resto de sistemas)

Una opción muy habitual para evitar esto (sobre todo si quieres ejecutar la aplicación en otra máquina sin tener todo el repositorio local de Maven presente), es usar un plugin de maven que "inyecta" las dependencias dentro del nuevo jar, como puede ser `maven-assembly-plugin`

Comment: Excelente respuesta Pablo! Entonces, ¿añado maven-assembly-plugin al .pom y me genera el .jar con todo lo necesario para que se ejecute? de ser así, ¿cuál sería la línea de código que debo agregar? Maven me ha hecho doler mucho la cabeza, hace horas que estoy con esto

Comment: No he encontrado documentación en castellano oficial, pero existen varios tutoriales o guías para configurarlo, por ejemplo: https://joanluk.wordpress.com/2013/10/20/como-crear-una-distribucion-a-traves-de-maven-assembly-plugin/
Para darte una configuración exacta me tocaría ponerme a investigar, ya que Spring boot (que es lo que uso en mi día a día) gestiona automáticamente estos detalles, así que te lo dejo como tarea

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta para añadir el código XML resultante de haber aplicado tu recomendación, aunque no me ha funcionado. Te agradecería si me echas una mano porque me voy a enloquecer con Maven jaja.

Comment: Vale, ya casi lo tengo. He conseguido el comando completo en Eclipse, he cambiado algunas cosas, como, por ejemplo, "-classpath" por "-cp", o "C:/laRuta/a/javaw.exe" por "java". Me ha quedado un comando con todas las dependencias, pero tengo una duda, al final del comando aparece esto "-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages Loquesea.Loquesea2.MyMain" ¿cómo cambio "XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages" por algo que me acepte la consola?

Comment: Resulta que, "C:/laRuta/a/javaw.exe" que mencioné anteriormente.. en realidad era la ruta a javaw propio de eclipse. Aquí te dejo la ruta: C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\eclipse-java-2021-03-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955\jre\bin\javaw.exe. Curiosamente, si reemplazo "java" nuevamente por esta ruta, sí funciona. Conclusión: pude ejecutarlo a través del CMD con el comando que me da eclipse, sólo con la diferencia de haber cambiado "-classpath" por "-cp" y ya. Ahora la duda es ¿cómo genero un .jar que contenga todo eso?